# List Mutex and Handle Names of processes with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, mutex, powershell-3.0

I'm curious on how to list the Mutex and Handle names that a process is using via powershell.

I didn't see anything online, and was curious if anyone else has done this. What I would like to do is search through and enumerate all Mutex names (and later on Handle names) and then compare them with known "good ones" or maybe, known bad ones - I haven't decided.